# How to convert ZXingBarcodeImageView to a PDFImage?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to convert my ZXingBarcodeImageView to a PDFImage to print it using SyncFusion? Is there a way I can access the image of a ZXingBarcodeImageView to draw in a PDF. I am using Syncfusion PDF to draw out my barcode.

Thank you in advance!

[image: a]

Comment: Which version of ZXing you are using ??

Comment: Have look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411031/zxing-pdf417-size-of-the-image

Comment: @Argon the latest version, 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28161/barcode-rendering-with-zxing-net-in-my-xamarin-forms-app) to create a BarcodeService interface and implement it in both platforms. I then convert that `Stream` to `PDFBitmap` to draw in my PDF (code below).

```
using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
        {
            document.PageSettings.Size = new SizeF(612, 350);
            document.PageSettings.Orientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape;
            document.PageSettings.SetMargins(0);
            // Add a page to the document
            PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

            //Create PDF graphics for the page
            PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;
            var qrImage = DependencyService.Get<IBarcodeService>().ConvertImageStream(Vin);
            PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(qrImage);

            graphics.DrawImage(image, 300, -50, 350, 350);
        }
```

and Viola!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can't convert `ZXingBarcodeImageView` to `PdfImagedirectly`.

Check the [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.Pdf.Base~Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics.PdfImage_members.html) of PdfImage .

**FromFile** -- Creates PdfImage from the specified file

**FromImage**  --  Creates a PdfImage from the existing System.Drawing.Image.

**FromStream**  -- Creates PdfImage from the specified data stream

You could try to save ZXingBarcodeImageView into local path , convert it to Image , get its stream and so on ..

Comment: Is there a way I could directly convert ZXingBarcodeImageView to a regular System.Drawing.Image? I don't need to save it locally, really I'm just trying to print the barcode in my PDF.